# Drop duplicates with some complex logic

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with two values, car_id and owner_type.

Based on the duplicates on car_id, I want to treat the values in a different way (based on the values) in that duplicated subset of owner_type.

If a car_id is duplicated, and taking into consideration that owner_type can only be 'owner' or 'lender':

- If the duplicated pair is both owner, fill the owner_type with missing value.
- If the duplicated pair is owner and lender (no matter which order), keep the owner.
- If the duplicated pair is both lender, fill the value owner_type with missing value.

The following initial data set:

| `' |  | car_id | owner_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | owner |  |
| 1 | 1 | owner |  |
| 2 | 2 | owner |  |
| 3 | 2 | lender |  |
| 4 | 3 | lender |  |
| 5 | 3 | owner |  |
| 6 | 4 | lender |  |
| 7 | 4 | lender | ' |

Should result into:

| ' |  | car_id | owner_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | N/A |  |
| 1 | 1 | N/A |  |
| 2 | 2 | owner |  |
| 3 | 2 | N/A |  |
| 4 | 3 | N/A |  |
| 5 | 3 | owner |  |
| 6 | 4 | N/A |  |
| 7 | 4 | N/A | ' |

Comment: where is your own attempt? good explanation of the problem and what the output looks like but feels more like a job spec as opposed to a question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
def get_owner(frame):
    # only owner or only lender
    if frame.nunique() == 1:
        return pd.Series([np.nan] * 2)
    return frame.replace('lender', np.nan)

# apply to each group of car_id and store in df
df['owner_type'] = df.groupby('car_id').owner_type.apply(get_owner).values
```

Result:

```py
   car_id owner_type
0       1        NaN
1       1        NaN
2       2      owner
3       2        NaN
4       3        NaN
5       3      owner
6       4        NaN
7       4        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful, so far I tried to play around with categories but this looks like a valid approach.